# How to add this entry in PNR_AddMultiElement api?

Tags: amadeus

I want to add this entry in PNR_AddMuleiElement API XML but it keeps throwing me errors.

Entry: SR FOID PPT-TBA/P1

My code

```
                $j++;
                $refn++;
                $params['dataElementsMaster']['dataElementsIndiv'][$j]['elementManagementData']['reference']['qualifier'] = 'SR';
                $params['dataElementsMaster']['dataElementsIndiv'][$j]['elementManagementData']['reference']['number'] = $refn;
                $params['dataElementsMaster']['dataElementsIndiv'][$j]['elementManagementData']['segmentName'] = 'SSR';
                $params['dataElementsMaster']['dataElementsIndiv'][$j]['serviceRequest']['ssr']['type'] = 'FOID';
                $params['dataElementsMaster']['dataElementsIndiv'][$j]['serviceRequest']['ssr']['companyId'] = $passport_required_airline;                
                $params['dataElementsMaster']['dataElementsIndiv'][$j]['serviceRequest']['ssr']['freetext'] = 'TBA';
                $params['dataElementsMaster']['dataElementsIndiv'][$j]['referenceForDataElement']['reference']['qualifier'] = "PP";
                $params['dataElementsMaster']['dataElementsIndiv'][$j]['referenceForDataElement']['reference']['number'] = $k;
```

Comment: In case you haven't figured it out yet, what are the errors?

Comment: Hi Heki i got it working now. But do you know how to add FP form if payment in PNR_AddMultiElement Api?

Comment: Ah, good. About the FP element, I have no experience with that, but I would try to fill `identification`, `creditCardCode`, `accountNumber`, `expiryDate`, `approvalCode`, and `currencyCode` where I think the last two are optional. Diners Club (`identification = CC, creditCardCode = DC`) have no approval code (CVV) for example.

Comment: Thanks Heki I will try that